# R: Customizing the Travelling Salesman Problem

Tags: r, algorithm, optimization, combinations

I am working with the R programming language.

I found this (very good) tutorial that shows how to implement the Genetic Algorithm for the Travelling Salesman Problem (for a set of European cities) in R: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/132872_620c10f340f348b88453d75ec99960ff.html

```
library(GA)
data("eurodist", package = "datasets")
D <- as.matrix(eurodist)


tourLength <- function(tour, distMatrix) {
   tour <- c(tour, tour[1])
   route <- embed(tour, 2)[,2:1]
   sum(distMatrix[route])
}

#Firness function to be maximized

tspFitness <- function(tour, ...) 1/tourLength(tour, ...)

GA <- ga(type = "permutation", fitness = tspFitness, distMatrix = D,
          min = 1, max = attr(eurodist, "Size"), popSize = 50, maxiter = 5000,
          run = 500, pmutation = 0.2)
```

In the end, the algorithm returns the order in which you should visit these cities (indexed by their number):

```
    summary(GA)

## Solutions              = 
##      x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10 x11 x12 x13 x14 x15 x16 x17 x18 x19
## [1,] 20  7 11  3  4  5 18 13 12   9  14   2  15   8  16  19   1  21  17
## [2,]  6 10 20  7 11  3  4  5 18  13  12   9  14   2  15   8  16  19   1
## [3,] 10  6 17 21  1 19 16  8 15   2  14   9  12  13  18   5   4   3  11
##      x20 x21
## [1,]   6  10
## [2,]  21  17
## [3,]   7  20
```

We can even see a visualization of the path returned by the algorithm:

[image]

**My Question:**

- Is it possible to "customize" this problem by adding some constraints? For instance, suppose you absolutely want to start your trip in Vienna - is there a way to tell the Genetic Algorithm to begin searching for the optimal path with the first city being Vienna?
- Is it possible to instruct the Genetic Algorithm to have certain cities in certain positions? For example, you want the first city to be Vienna and the sixth city to be Athens - and then, search for the optimal path given these constraints?

**Is it possible to customize the Genetic Algorithm in R to take these "considerations" into account when optimizing the Travelling Salesman Problem?**

Comment: More relevant for https://or.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You would need to adapt your crossover/mutation operators to do that efficiently (otherwise most of individuals will be infeasible). For TSP problems you can use `TSP` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment. When dealing with constraints in genetic algorithm you have two options:

- incorporate conditions in fitness function
- insure that genetic operators create feasible solutions

With first approach you need to decide what to do with infeasible solutions (ex. penalization) and that is extremely problem dependent. If conditions are hard to achieve most of the solutions that evolutionary algorithm creates in the process will be infeasible and it will cause premature convergence.

Which approach to adapt is problem dependent, I'll show you how to implement 2nd approach for this problem.

**matrix transformation**:

```
transformMatrix <- function(fixed_points, D){
  
  if(length(fixed_points) == 0) return(D)
  
  p <- integer(nrow(D))
  pos <- match(names(fixed_points), colnames(D))
  p[fixed_points] <- pos 
  p[-fixed_points] <- sample(setdiff(seq_len(nrow(D)), pos))

  D[p, p]
}
```

goal of this function is to permute rows and columns of matrix to get cities to their specified  positions:

```
popSize <- 100
fixed_points <- c(
  "Vienna" = 1,
  "Athens" = 6
)
D_perm <- transformMatrix(fixed_points, D)
```

**feasible initial population**

```
feasiblePopulation <- function(n, size, fixed_points){
  
  positions <- setdiff(seq_len(n), fixed_points)
  
  m <- matrix(0, size, n)
  if(length(fixed_points) > 0){
    
    m[, fixed_points] <- rep(fixed_points, each = size)
    
    for(i in seq_len(size))
      m[i, -fixed_points] <- sample(positions)
    
  } else {
    
    for(i in seq_len(size))
      m[i,] <- sample(positions)
  }
  
  m
}
```

this function creates feasible solutions

**mutation**

```
mutation <- function(n, fixed_points){
  
  positions <- setdiff(seq_len(n), fixed_points)
  
  function(obj, parent){
    
    vec <- obj@population[parent,]
    if(length(positions) < 2) return(vec) 
    
    indices <- sample(positions, 2)
    replace(vec, indices, vec[rev(indices)])
  }
}
```

we need to ensure that mutation operator keeps fixed positions in place. This function returns one such mutation operator.

**fitness function**

```
fitness <- function(tour, distMatrix) {
  
  tour <- c(tour, tour[1])
  route <- embed(tour, 2)[,2:1]
  1/sum(distMatrix[route])
}
```

We want to minimize distance hence taking the reciprocal.

**optimization step**

```
res <- ga(
  type = "permutation",
  fitness = fitness,
  distMatrix = D_perm,
  lower = 1,
  upper = nrow(D_perm),
  mutation = mutation(nrow(D_perm), fixed_points),
  crossover = gaperm_pmxCrossover,
  suggestions = feasiblePopulation(nrow(D_perm), popSize, fixed_points),
  popSize = popSize,
  maxiter = 5000,
  run = 500,
  pmutation = 0.2
)
```

`gaperm_pmxCrossover` will insure that fixed positions stay fixed during the crossover process (that is why I didn't write custom crossover operator)

**solution**

```
colnames(D_perm)[res@solution[1,]]
solution_distance <- 1 / fitness(res@solution[1,], D_perm)
```

Also first city is last (route)

Comment: @ Det: Thank you so much for your answer! I have been trying to study your answer, I think it will take me some time to fully understand what you have done here. I noticed that when I left "popSize = popSize" the code does not work - so I manually replace "popSize" with some number (e.g. 500)

Comment: Is it possible to obtain the total distance of the chosen path? Currently, I am manually adding all the distances between each pair of points. Is there a faster way to do this using the code you provided?

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71625643/r-different-ways-to-name-matrices I tried to apply your code to a new problem. Thanks!

Comment: `popSize` is input parameter, forgot to put it in code. You can calculate distance using `fitness`. Code on that link works fine for me (just put `D_perm <- transformMatrix(fixed_points, dists)` or `D <- dists`. Just keep in mind that for such a small problems  (only 24 possibilities) you can 'brute force' the best solution very easy and fast.