# More Efficient Method for Calculating Cumulative distances

Tags: r

I have a group of inspectors (let's say 25) who I need to send to locations.
I'm starting with a reasonably simple method of finding the closest site to an inspector, then go to the next closest and the next and the next. The problem is that I can't find a nice vectorized solution, so I end up with a set of loops, which end up being extremely slow.

So I'm looking for a faster way of doing this.

```
library("tidyverse")
library("sf")
library("units")
library("spData")

#generate some random points
UK <- world[world$name_long == "United Kingdom", 0]
Data <- st_sample(UK, size = 1000, type = "random", crs = st_crs(4326)) %>% st_as_sf()
Examiner_Locations_all  <- st_sample(UK, size = 25, type = "random", crs = st_crs(4326)) %>% st_as_sf()

#How many exams per day
ExamsPerDay <- 4

#Leave the original Data alone
ExamAssets <- Data 
Examiner_Locations_all$distance <-  set_units(0, "m")

#While we still have assets to check
while(nrow(ExamAssets > 0)){
  
#because we have some examiners in the same place (in the real data set) we need to do the closest x assets per examiner

for(i in 1:nrow(Examiner_Locations_all)){

  Examiner <- Examiner_Locations_all[i,]
  #Find the closest site and then get the distance from start point to site 
  Closest_AP <- st_nearest_feature(Examiner, ExamAssets)
  Examiner_Locations_all[i,]$distance <- Examiner_Locations_all[i,]$distance + 
                                         st_distance(Examiner_Locations_all[i,], ExamAssets[Closest_AP,], by_element=TRUE)
    
  for(x in 1:ExamsPerDay){
    #Find the next nearest feature
    Next_AP <- st_nearest_feature(ExamAssets[Closest_AP,], ExamAssets[-c(Closest_AP),])
    #Add on the travel distance
    Examiner_Locations_all[i,]$distance <- Examiner_Locations_all[i,]$distance + st_distance(ExamAssets[Closest_AP,], ExamAssets[Next_AP,], by_element=TRUE)
    #Drop the site out of the dataset
    ExamAssets <- ExamAssets[-c(Closest_AP),]
    Closest_AP <- Next_AP 
    }
    
  #Add on the distance to return home.
  Examiner_Locations_all[i,]$distance <- Examiner_Locations_all[i,]$distance + 
    st_distance(Examiner_Locations_all[i,], ExamAssets[Closest_AP,], by_element=TRUE)
  
  
}  
  
}
```

I've got 1000 points here, but the actual data is about 20 times bigger.

Comment: You've scratched your head over [Traveling Salesman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71612530/r-customizing-the-travelling-salesman-problem), though it appears your's is a mTSP? (accumulated distances discussed in comments).

Comment: Ah! I knew it was TSP adjacent, but this was a bit of pre-TSP exploratory work.
The link is most welcome!